# How can I get the name of a specific Discord role?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot for my server with many international users. One issue we always run into is coordinating times because were all around the world. I wanted to make this bot be able to tell you what time it is for a specific user. I already have all of my users have a role with the format "UTC[-10 through +14]" that says what time zone they are in. I already have the function that when you give it a UTC offset, it will give you the time there. My question is, how can I get the UTC offset of someone given their name.
For example, I have a user `@User1#0000` with the role `UTC-05`. They also might have other roles (not timezone roles). How can I get that `-05` out of someones roles just given their name?

Comment: So you're asking for how can you know what roles a user have?

Comment: @Androz2091 No, I’m asking specifically how can I get the name of a specific type of role my server uses. We have a whole bunch of roles that contain UTC codes, among other roles, and I need to get the UTC code of a given user.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to get a member's roles, you just need to use the `roles` property `member`, now to get just the timezone role, you can use the `.find` function that [collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) has and look for "UTC" at the start of the role name,

```
let utcRole = member.roles.find(role => role.name.startsWith('UTC'))
```

Now, the harder part is parsing the role name to get just the offset from it, we can do that using a regular expression and the match function, we want to isolate the +14, the regex for isolating it would be `[\+\-][0-9]*[^\[\]]`, so adding that to our sudo code,

```
let utcRole = member.roles.find(role => role.name.startsWith('UTC'))

let offset = utcRole.name.match(/[\+\-][0-9]*[^\[\]]/)[0]
```

And there we go! you will have the offset that you wanted, now one important thing to remember is that you have the offset as a string, and by what you said you will use it as a number, to convert strings in to numbers in javascript we use `parseInt()`, so to convert it to a number,

```
let number = parseInt(offset)
```